# How can i modify my razor syntax for checkbox?

Tags: razor

I am trying lots of time to change class and inline styles too.
but not getting any change.

This is my html code (what i want to modify my checkbox):

```
<div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-primary mb5">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxExample1">
    <label for="checkboxExample1"></label>
</div>
```

This is my Razor Syntax:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m =>m.isNewlyEnrolled, new {@style="width:25px; height:25px;", @class = "checkbox-custom checkbox-primary mb5", id="checkboxExample1"})
```

Comment: Is the html snippet what you *want* or what you *get*?

Comment: Also, style is not normally set in the razor view. It’s done by css classes.